# Setting alarm on with a single click

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, launcher, alarm

I'm looking for a way to set an alarm on my android 4.0 phone with Nova Launcher with a single click. An ideal solution for me would be: I install an alarm clock app (if necessary), create alarms in it and save them with aliases (for instance 5:30-"gym", 6:30-"sleep in", 7:30-"weekend"), then the app creates 3 shortcuts with respective aliaces or it shows a widget with these three options and I place those on my home screen. So when I finally decide whether I want to go to the gym tomorrow or not, I just unlock the phone and click the corresponding button - clean and simple. Let me know if there's a solution that might work. I'm even willing to try another Launcher, if one of them has it. Thanks!

Comment: The best that I can recommend is two clicks. If you create multiple alarms in the clock app, you can label them with different names. Then you just open the alarm app (mine is set to open when I click on the analog clock on my main screen) and turn the alarm on you are interested in. I don't know of any apps that will have a widget to enable a single alarm. If you can't configure a widget to open up just the alarms, you can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.solo12zw74.alarmshortcut to create a shortcut to the alarm app on your homescreen.

Comment: Thanks! I had two clicks at some point, when I had a separate Alarm Clock app start, when I clicked on a Watches widget. But having time shown to me in notifications _and_ in a separate widget seemed like such a waste ... Looked up the app you suggested. The funny thing is that quickly turning on alarm clock seems to be a Russian thing :)

Comment: You can do this with tasker. Let me know if you would like me to submit an answer with details.

Comment: @bassmadrigal gave the app a try and it fails 100% on my 4.0 ICS. Too bad.

Comment: Bummer... If you have a launcher that can do shortcuts, like Apex or Nova, (or get the app Any Shortcut), you can do it that way as well. For launcher shortcuts (the following is for Apex, but Nova or the app should be similar), go to the homescreen and long-press on there and go to Shortcuts -> Activities -> Clock -> Alarms (on mine there were two, but both worked).

Answer (score -1):

Buy a Samsung S3 - it alarm app has a built in widget function that allows you to set a widget, and then assign the alarm you want to it. Its a 2 block widget and you can toggle it on and off, plus it provides details about the alarm.

Perhaps you could see on XDA if someone could pull the app for you and then you could try running it on ICS.

I am surprised there isn't another app out there that is similar.

Comment: *Buy a Samsung S3...* - Buy a Veyron Bugatti! I wonder when you'll *suggest* us to buy the [Big Ben](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4yihaLXbx1rxs1r1o1_500.jpg).